# save_post_{$post->post_type} action firing on second save

Tags: metabox, actions

I have custom metabox checkbox on CPT in my plugin. I want to fire an action and save new option when I save this post. But no matter how many times I tried it's saving option value only on second save. First post save - nothing happens, second post save - the value is saved. What's wrong with this code?

Here's my code:

```
add_action( 'save_post_theme_template', 'clean_deactivated_theme_templates_post_meta', 10, 2 );
function clean_deactivated_theme_templates_post_meta( $post_id, $post ) {
  $location = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_est_template_location', true );

  if ( 'header' === $location ) {
    update_option( '_est_cpt_save_', 'header', 'yes' );
  } else {
    update_option( '_est_cpt_save_', 'other', 'yes' );          
  }

}
```

Comment: Where did you find the `save_post_theme_template()` function?  Is there any documentation you read up on about it somewhere that you can share?  I've never seen it and a google search doesn't return any results.

Comment: theme_template is the dymanic part of WordPress hook, you can read about it here - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/ It fires every time you save your custom post.

Comment: So is your CPT named `theme_template`?  If that's the case, I believe you should be using `add_post_meta` & `update_post_meta` rather than `update_options`.

Comment: yep, that's correct. I'm just just testing it with option table. But it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: So it's not working with the `update_post_meta()` either...  do you have the code with that attempt?

Comment: Yes, I tried update_post_meta() and had the same result. Looks like when I save the post and save_post hook is firing my meta is not saved yet. I think something wrong with my custom metabox code. When I'm testing metabox plugin instead I can get meta every time I save the post.

Comment: The part I'm unsure of is your `if ( 'header' === $location ) {`... ...when first creating a post that variable may not be found, or it'll be undefined I think, which means that instead of executing it'll throw an error.  I'd put that check in the metabox itself by setting 'other' as the default.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to move the check for whether or not the `$location === header` into the metabox then use the following to save the meta data.

Like this:

```
//In your metabox before the fields
$location       = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_est_template_location', true );
if( empty( $location ) || $location != 'header' ) :
    $location = 'other';
endif;
```

Then, when saving, you've already addressed everything else and it's a straightforward saving process.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'clean_deactivated_theme_templates_post_meta', 1, 2 );
function clean_deactivated_theme_templates_post_meta( $post_id, $post ) {
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if( !isset( $_POST['theme_template_fields'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['theme_template_fields'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    $theme_template_meta['_est_template_location']      = esc_textarea( $_POST['_est_template_location'] );
    foreach( $theme_template_meta as $key => $value ) :
        if( 'revision' === $post->post_type ) {
            return;
        }
        if( get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, false ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value );
        } else {
            add_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value);
        }
        if( !$value ) {
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, $key );
        }
    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my metabox code is more complex than this. What I've discovered is that I can't retrieve metadata upon post save even with basic metabox code. So I've decided to switch to Metabox plugin, which works perfectly.